# cruisecontrol.net file watcher

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is there a file watcher task insdie cruisecontrol.net??? I am trying to see if I can have cruiscontrol watch a file and when the file gets updated, then runs my executable.

Comment: unknown you should really be marking the correct answers as answered. You have not been doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want [File system control block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filesystem+Source+Control+Block).

Comment: Igor, do you know if it is possible to poll for ANY changes to a directory instead. What I would be polling is not the source, but the binaries ...

Comment: From what I remember when I was using CC.NET, File System source control works on any files, it doesn't even know what a "source" or a "binary" is. It just detects changes on the file system. So the short answer is YES :)